# Ошибка reference to non-static member funtionпри использовании QtConcurrent

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5

Пытался понять каким образом Qt может обрабатывать данные без сигналов и слотов. Наткнулся на примеры с QtConcurrent, однако функции сделанные по примеру не работают. Я использовал следующий код:

```
extern int ping::doPing(QString ip){


       QString command = "ping";
       QStringList args;
       args << "-w" <<  "1" <<  ip;
       ping_process->start(command, args);
       ping_process->waitForStarted(100);

       ping_process->waitForFinished(100);
       QString out = ping_process->readAll();
       if(out.contains("ms"))
       {
           is_Avail = true;
       }
       return is_Avail;

};

void ping::startCommand(QString ip){
    if(ping_process){
        int result = 0;
        QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(doPing,ip);//reference to non-static member function must be called
        result = future.result();
    }
}
```

Как можно выполнить подобный код с использованием QtConcurrent?

Comment: Может, я что-то упускаю, но в примерах в документации, которые я просмотрел, функция, передаваемая в ```QtConcurrent::run``` не является функцией-членом класса.

Comment: Вряд ли в текущей ситуации именно это влияет. Сама функция и ссылка на эту функцию определяются правильно. Пытался делать явный указатель (this -> doPing) - к результату такое событие не привело

Comment: Вынесение функции doPing за пределы класса ни к чему не приводит. Ошибка не меняется...

Comment: Вы оказались правы, Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать сделать лямбда-функцию:

```
QtConcurrent::run([this](QString ip){
    doPing(ip);
}, ip);
```

Если бы можно было передавать в QtConcurrent функцию-член класса, то хоть где-то должен был появиться указать this. Иначе непонятно, функцию какого экземпляра этого класса вызывать. Лямбда же не является членом класса, однако она захватывает указатель this, и поэтому может вызывать функции того объекта, который захватила.

Comment: Попытался применить предложенный вами вариант: столкнулся с ошибкой "no viable conversion from QFuture<void> to QFuture<int>"
      
Если верить тексту ошибки, то лямбда функция в QtConcurrent - исключительно невозвратная? Т.е. Как в текущем случае невозможно переопределить void на int?

Comment: Кажется я разобрался в проблеме, благодарю.Получилось примерно следующее:

```
void ping::startCommand(QString ip){

    if(ping_process){
        while (true){
            int result = 0;
            auto res = QtConcurrent::run([this](QString ip){
                    int res = ping::doPing(ip);
                    return res;
        },ip);
            qDebug()<< "result is" << res.result();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё верно, я просто не посмотрел, какой у вас тип возвращаемого значения у doPing. Но вы дальше и сами разобрались.